# Job title of a person who does web animation

Tags: website-design, animation, terminology, designers

Does anyone know the job title for a person who develop websites just front-end but is heavily involved with creating animations, WebGL and all moving elements?

I know it wouldn't be just a front-end developer because of heavy animation work, just can't find what these people are called.

Comment: Web Animator...?

Answer (score 5):

There are different names. Probably the most common one nowadays is *creative developer* because often times agencies these days will not only be creating things for the web but also installations, apps, VR/AR experiences, and so forth.

I specialize in web animation and just call myself a frontend developer most of the time. Over time you'll come to learn that titles don't mean *that* much, although they do mean something.

Comment: That's what I think it is. Around here I recently heard _creative designer_ ... _cringe_